# Unlink coupon form on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, coupon

Which file do I need to edit if I don’t want user to click the link to apply the coupon code?

In simple, I want no LINK to be clicked on.

I want the apply coupon appear below the text "Have a coupon?" so that user can ALWAYS see the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

This can be done very easily using dedicated `woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', 'custom_checkout_coupon_message', 20, 1 );
function custom_checkout_coupon_message( $message ) {
    ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready( function($){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('form.checkout_coupon').css('display','block');
                }, 300);
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    // HERE your custom message
    return __( 'Have a coupon?', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a class="showcoupon-off">' . __( 'Below you can enter your coupon code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: YES! This is what I meant! Thank you so much! Finally!

Comment: @nani.nsr you could paste the code inside the function in a related convenient template for example…