# How to change "Have a coupon?" text in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, gettext

I'm trying to translate "Have a coupon?" text in Woocommerce checkout page using this code:

```
function custom_strings_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'HAVE A COUPON?' : 
        $translated_text =  __( 'TIENES UN CUPÓN?', '__x__' );
        break;
}

  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_strings_translation', 20, 3);
```

But It doesn't work.

Please can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't work because the text is not in capitals and you are not using the right variable.

**There is 2 ways to change this text *(the second way seems the best)*:**

1) Using `gettext` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_strings_translation', 20, 3);
function custom_strings_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $text == 'Have a coupon?' ){
        $translated_text =  __( 'Tienes un cupón?', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) Using `woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message` filter hook that will allow you more changes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', 'custom_checkout_coupon_message', 20, 1 );
function custom_checkout_coupon_message( $notice ) {
    return __( 'Tienes un cupón?', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Haga clic aquí para ingresar su código', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>'
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related:

- [Unlink coupon form on Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272869/unlink-coupon-form-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/49273237#49273237)
- [Some `gettext` filter hook code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+gettext)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't know why but my question change here. My problem is that I have other strings apart from: "Have a coupon?" like "Shopping Cart" (this is my site: https://brisaperu.com/ ) and I can't translate none of them. I try to use the first code you gave me with "Shopping Cart", but still does not translate.

Comment: This example also helped me to understand how to code this: https://gist.github.com/maxrice/8551024?permalink_comment_id=2882801#gistcomment-2882801